# Turning off scroll listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
p.initInfiniteScroll = function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', this.infiniteScroll.bind(this));
};

p.terminateInfiniteScroll = function(){
    $(window).off('scroll', this.infiniteScroll);
};

p.infiniteScroll = function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

        this.loadMore();
    }
};

p.loadMore = function(){

    console.log('load more');
    this.terminateInfiniteScroll();

};
```

I init my infinite scroll, then upon scroll I call loadMore, inside this function I try to turn off the infinite scroll but this has no effect - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep reference of your "binded" function

```
var myFunc = this.infiniteScroll.bind(this);

p.initInfiniteScroll = function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', myFunc);
};

p.terminateInfiniteScroll = function(){
    $(window).off('scroll', myFunc);
};
```

Comment: why do i need to create a var for it, why cannot I just reference the method itself?